# Gulp mobile connection

Tags: mobile, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

I had created mobile WiFi hotspot from my tablet and i had connected my laptop and mobile phone to it.
I'm trying to run Browsersync on those mobiles. My external ip adress was gathered from Browsersync -> Overview External. I pasted that IP adress in mobile browsers but they can't connect.
Here are gulp terminal lines:

```
[09:31:58] Using gulpfile ~/Dokumenty/Frontend/TESTgulp/gulpfile.js
[09:31:58] Starting 'scripts'...
[09:31:58] Finished 'scripts' after 18 ms
[09:31:58] Starting 'style'...
[09:31:58] Finished 'style' after 6.4 ms
[09:31:58] Starting 'watch'...
[09:31:58] Finished 'watch' after 17 ms
[09:31:58] Starting 'html'...
[09:31:58] Finished 'html' after 824 μs
[09:31:58] Starting 'browser-sync'...
[09:31:59] Finished 'browser-sync' after 489 ms
[09:31:59] Starting 'default'...
[09:31:59] Finished 'default' after 14 μs
[BS] Access URLs:
 -------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://142.128.13.4:3000
 -------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://142.128.13.4:3001
 -------------------------------------
[BS] Serving files from: ./app/
[09:32:00] Starting 'scripts'...
[09:32:00] Finished 'scripts' after 1.64 ms
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
[BS] 1 file changed (main.min.js)
```

What should I do? Can that be fault to that it is WiFi hotspot from my tablet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was gwuf blocking incoming connections at my Linux Mint 18.1.
Disable your firewall, it's that easy!